# Two HTML forms on the site, but only one works

Tags: html, forms, submit

I am developing website www.deks.org.rs and there I have two important forms.

Before all, when I say "form works" it means that form data is sent on e-mail I wrote in .php file in the background. When I say "form doesn't work" it means that I can't get data from this form on given e-mail.

Form "Pisanje sazetaka" works, but form "Prijava" don't. How I can solve this problem?

Code for first working form:

```js
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
 _("mybtn").disabled = true;
 _("status").innerHTML = 'Molimo sačekajte.';
 var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
 formdata.append( "i", _("i").value );
 formdata.append( "a", _("a").value );
 formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
 formdata.append( "t", _("t").value );
 formdata.append( "nr", _("nr").value );
 formdata.append( "as", _("as").value );
 formdata.append( "ia", _("ia").value );
 formdata.append( "u", _("u").value );
 formdata.append( "c", _("c").value );
 formdata.append( "mm", _("mm").value );
 formdata.append( "re", _("re").value );
 formdata.append( "za", _("za").value );
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php" );
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
   if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
    _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Hvala Vam '+_("n").value+', Vaš sažetak je poslat.</h2>';
   } else {
    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    _("mybtn").disabled = false;
   }
  }
 }
 ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

```html
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
  <label for="fname">Autor</label>
  <input type="text" id="n" name="name" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Institucija</label>
  <input type="text" id="i" name="inst" value="" required>
  <label for="adr">Adresa</label>
  <input type="text" id="a" name="adr" value="" required>
  <label for="em">E-mail</label>
  <input type="text" id="e" name="email" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Telefon</label>
  <input type="text" id="t" name="phone" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Naziv rada</label>
  <input type="text" id="nr" name="rad" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Autori</label>
  <input type="text" id="as" name="inst" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Institucije autora</label>
  <input type="text" id="ia" name="names" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Uvod</label>
  <input type="text" id="u" name="uvod" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Cilj</label>
  <input type="text" id="c" name="cilj" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Materijal i metodi</label>
  <input type="text" id="mm" name="mm" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Rezultati</label>
  <input type="text" id="re" name="rez" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Zaključak</label>
  <input type="text" id="za" name="zak" value="" rows="10" >
 <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span></p>
</form>
```

Code for second form, which is not working:

```js
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
 _("mybtn2").disabled = true;
 _("status2").innerHTML = 'Molimo sačekajte.';
 var formdata2 = new FormData();
 formdata2.append( "pi", _("pi").value );
 formdata2.append( "pp", _("pp").value );
 formdata2.append( "pb", _("pb").value );
 formdata2.append( "pj", _("pj").value );
 formdata2.append( "pu", _("pu").value );
 formdata2.append( "pg", _("pg").value );
 formdata2.append( "ppb", _("ppb").value );
 formdata2.append( "pt", _("pt").value );
 formdata2.append( "pfx", _("pfx").value );
 formdata2.append( "pmt", _("pmt").value );
 formdata2.append( "pem", _("pem").value );
 formdata2.append( "pko", _("pko").value );
 formdata2.append( "psm", _("psm").value );
 formdata2.append( "psd", _("psd").value );
 formdata2.append( "pdp", _("pdp").value );
 formdata2.append( "pdo", _("pdo").value );
 formdata2.append( "pnk", _("pnk").value );
 formdata2.append( "ppib", _("ppib").value );
 formdata2.append( "ptelk", _("ptelk").value );
 
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open( "POST", "example_parserPL.php" );
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
   if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
    _("my_formPL").innerHTML = '<h2>Hvala Vam '+_("pi").value+', Vaša prijava je poslata.</h2>';
   } else {
    _("status2").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    _("mybtn2").disabled = false;
   }
  }
 }
 ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

```html
<form id="my_formPL" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
  
  <!-- Informacije o kandidatu -->
  <label for="fname">Ime</label>
  <input type="text" id="pi" name="name" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Prezime</label>
  <input type="text" id="pp" name="inst" value="" required>
  <label for="adr">Broj licence</label>
  <input type="text" id="pb" name="adr" value="" required>
  <label for="em">JMBG</label>
  <input type="text" id="pj" name="email" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Ustanova</label>
  <input type="text" id="pu" name="phone" value="">
  <label for="lname">Grad</label>
  <input type="text" id="pg" name="rad" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Adresa ustanove</label>
  <input type="text" id="pa" name="inst" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Poštanski broj</label>
  <input type="text" id="ppb" name="names" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Telefon (posao)</label>
  <input type="text" id="pt" name="uvod" value="" required>
  <label for="lname">Faks</label>
  <input type="text" id="pfx" name="cilj" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Mobilni telefon</label>
  <input type="text" id="pmt" name="mm" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">E-mail</label>
  <input type="text" id="pem" name="rez" value="" rows="10" >
  <br><br>
  
  <!-- Kotizacije -->
  <table id="customers">
<tr>
    <th colspan = "3">Cena kotizacija</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Učesnici</th>
    <th>Kotizacija do 01.02.2018.</th>
    <th>Kotizacija od 01.02.2018.</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lekari</td>
    <td>(1) 10.000 RSD</td>
    <td>(2) 14.000 RSD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Medicinske sestre</td>
    <td>(3) 5.000 RSD</td>
    <td>(4) 9.000 RSD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mladi lekari (do 30 god. starosti)<br>i studenti</td>
    <td>(5) 4.000 RSD</td>
    <td>(6) 8.000 RSD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kotizacija za pridružene<br>osobe učesnika DEKS18</td>
    <td>(7) 3.000 RSD</td>
    <td>(8) 4.000 RSD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dnevna kotizacija<br>za sve kategorije</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>(9) 5.000 RSD</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
 
    <br>
    <label for="lname">Odlučujem se za KOTIZACIJU pod rednim brojem (broj u zagradi ispred cene):</label>
  <input type="text" id="pko" name="pko" value="" rows="10" >
  <br><br>
    
 <!-- Informacije o smestaju -->
 <table id="customers">
<tr>
    <th colspan = "5">Smeštaj</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan = "4">CENA PO DANU / PO OSOBI NA BAZI NOĆENJA SA DORUČKOM <br> UKLJUČENI BORAVIŠNA TAKSA, OSIGURANJE I PDV</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hotel</th>
    <th>Jednokrevetna <br> soba</th>
    <th>Dvokrevetna <br> soba</th>
    <th>Trokrevetna <br> soba</th>
    <th>Doplata za <br> polupansion</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mona **** BB</td>
    <td>(1) 75 EUR</td>
    <td>(2) 50 EUR</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10 EUR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Palisad **** BB</td>
    <td>(3) 65 EUR</td>
    <td>(4) 50 EUR</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8 EUR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Palisad **** <br> Superior BB</td>
    <td>(5) 70 EUR</td>
    <td>(6) 60 EUR</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>8 EUR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Čigota *** BB</td>
    <td>(7) 55 EUR</td>
    <td>(8) 35 EUR</td>
        <td>(9) 35 EUR</td>
        <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
    
    <br>
    <label for="lname">Odlučujem se za SMEŠTAJ pod rednim brojem (broj u zagradi ispred cene):</label>
  <input type="text" id="psm" name="psm" value="" rows="10" >
  <br><br>
    <!-- Ostale informacije -->
    U slučaju smeštaja u dvokrevetnoj sobi potrebno je navesti ime osobe sa kojom delite sobu. <br> 
    <label for="lname">Sobu delim sa:</label>
  <input type="text" id="psd" name="sdel" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Datum polaska:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pdd" name="dol" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Datum odlaska:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pdo" name="odl" value="" rows="10" >
    <br><br> CENA SMEŠTAJA JE ISKAZANA U EURIMA <br>

* plaćanje isključivo u dinarskoj protivrednosti po prodajnom kursu Banca Intesa ad na dan uplate <br><br>

<table id="customers">
<tr>
    <th colspan = "5">NAČIN PLAĆANJA</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan = "2">Fizičko lice</td>
    <td colspan = "3">GOTOVINSKI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan = "5">Za ispostavljanje predračuna za pravna lica uz prijavu je potrebno dostaviti:</td>
</tr>
</table> <br>
 <label for="lname">Naziv kompanije (pravno lice):</label>
  <input type="text" id="pnk" name="nkom" value="" rows="10" >
<label for="lname">PIB kompanije:</label>
  <input type="text" id="ppib" name="pib" value="" rows="10" >
  <label for="lname">Tel/Fax kompanije:</label>
  <input type="text" id="ptelk" name="tfk" value="" rows="10" >



<br><br>

PRIJAVNI LIST JE SASTAVNI DEO OPŠTIH INFORMACIJA <br>

Na osnovu prijave Izvršni organizator će izvršiti rezervaciju i poslati predračun sa predvidjenim rokom uplate. <br>

Sve rezervacije za koje uplata nije izvršena u datom roku na predračunu biće stornirane bez obaveze obaveštavanja učesnika. <br> Organizator zadržava pravo da promeni cene za neuplaćene usluge u slučaju izmene deviznog kursa. <br>

Za eventualno otkazivanje aranžmana važe opšti uslovi putovanja EASY TRAVEL& EVENTS. <br><br>

<a href="http://easytravel.rs/kongresi/prvi-srpski-kongres-decije-endokrinologije/" target="_parent">"EASY TRAVEL & EVENTS d.o.o."</a> 18000 Niš Prvomajska 4 a, Srbija <br>

Račun: 160-367847-07 Banca Intesa ad <br>

Licenca OTP 23/2015

<br><br>

Ukoliko želite da umesto ove online prijavu Vašu prijavu popunite korišćenjem Word formulara (preuzmite formular <a href="raw/prijavnilist.doc">ovde</a>) isti pošaljite na kongres@easytravel.rs. <br> Molimo Vas da se ne prijavljujte na oba načina.
 <br><br>
    
 <input id="mybtn2" type="submit" value="Pošalji prijavu!"> <span id="status"></span></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Using jQuery it would be something like this for both forms `$("form").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); 
var $form=$(this); res = $(this).find("#pi").length=1?$("#pi").val(): $("#n").val() ; $.post("example_parserPL.php",$(this9.serialize(),function(data) {
  $form.html('<h2>Hvala Vam '+res+', Vaša prijava je poslata.</h2>');
});`

Comment: Any console or server errors?

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for answer, but please tell me where to put this code you gave to me in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you decide to use jQuery, you can place it inside a `$(function() { ... });` in a script tag right after `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code for the second form :

```
ajax.send( formdata );
```

I feel like you forgot to change that line.

Comment: I have changed that, thank you. But form is still not submitted on e-mail. Still need help.

Comment: From what I see you got two undefined id's:
status2 and pdp. This combined with the wrong formdata variable is probably blocking your execution. Try and fix those and have a look in the console (ctrl+shift+i) if there is any other error .